# Python Fast data import column-wide

Tags: python, pandas, import, dask

I'm using the following code to import 2 columns (trigger and amplitude) out of 3 from 500 `*.txt` files :

```
    from glob import glob
    import pandas

    dataFileList = glob( '*.txt' )
    nbDataSamplesFiles = len(dataFileList)
    amplitudes = []
    colnames = ['time','trigger','amplitude']
    for dataFileName in dataFileList :
        #Method4
        data = pandas.read_csv( dataFileName, delim_whitespace=True, skipinitialspace=True, names = colnames ) #Environ 4.5s pour 500 fichiers
        trigger1 = data['trigger'].tolist()
        amplitude1 = data.amplitude.tolist() #another way
        amplitudes.append( amplitude1 ) #list of lists

    amplitudes = np.asarray( amplitudes ) #matrix nbFiles x nbSamples
```

It takes about 3.5 seconds to do the job.

I need it to be much faster, is there a way to do it using the same or another python module ?

And how can I achieve it ?

UPDATE 1 : Using `dask`

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

amplitudes = []
for dataFileName in dataFileList :
    df = dd.read_csv(urlpath = dataFileName, delim_whitespace=True, skipinitialspace=True, names = colnames )
    trigger1 = df.trigger.values
    amplitude1 = df.amplitude.values
    amplitudes.append( amplitude1 ) #list of arrays
```

I want to check the content of amplitude1 :

```
ipdb> amplitude1[111:121]
*** ValueError: ('Arrays chunk sizes are unknown: %s', (nan,))
```

Any idea ?

Comment: colnames does not change during the loop. Why not put it outside the loop - not sure what optimisations are done in python, but there is a chance it may make things (slightly) faster.

Comment: @KolaB I've put it outside the loop and didn't gain much, in fact I didn't the difference but nice remark anyway

Comment: In that case it may be better to put it back inside the loop - to keep in the scope in which it is used? I guess the interpreter is making the necessary optimisations...

Comment: Are you able to convert your data to another format, like Parquet?  http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/06/28/use-parquet

Comment: @MRocklin Hi, well I don't know it yet. Our people are using a [picoscope](https://www.picotech.com/oscilloscope/2000/picoscope-2000-specifications) but I don't how they are fetching the data. They just hand the data files to me

Comment: @MRocklin BTW : My data files are not really CSV files because the columns are separated by whitespaces.

Comment: Do I understand that trigger is the same in every file, so your real task is to produce a NxM array of values? A `dask.delayed` wrapping of ``np.loadtxt`, followed by `dask.array.from_delayed`, `dask.array.stack` sounds like the way to go.

Comment: @mdurant Actually, I'm using the trigger to select the amplitude values when the `trigger > 0` The resulting matrix is at most `500 x rows`

Comment: @MRocklin Maybe the conversion to Parquet format will take some time. So I prefer the data to be converted before the import, I will check this with my people. From what I read, It seems your idea of using parquet format is very efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

Dask might be good option to try for handling large collections/directory of CSVs - Go through [Dask Docs - Specific Usecase](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/use-cases.html)

Comment: When trying this :


    `df = dd.read_csv( dataFileName, delim_whitespace=True, skipinitialspace=True, names = colnames );
    df['trigger'].tolist()`

I get the following error : `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'tolist'`

Comment: you are trying to use params for `pandas.read_csv`instead of `dask.dataframe.read_csv`("dd.read_csv" in your code). Refer params of `dask.dataframe.read_csv` - http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html

Comment: @Ok the correct line is `df = dd.read_csv(urlpath = dataFileName, delim_whitespace=True, skipinitialspace=True, names = colnames )` but still I cannot fetch my data : `trigger1 = list( df.trigger )` says `NotImplementedError`

Comment: Can you share the snippet of code you have implemented now for dask?

Comment: As multi-line code is not possible in comments, I just edit the end of my question, please find the new implementation here

Comment: This is breaking on first iteration of for loop or any other further iteration? can you please check that ?Working fine on my PC.

Comment: @Tany I'm using Macos X 10 and it's breaking on all iterations

Comment: @Tany I replaced the `tolist()` method by the `.values` property, please have a look at the update in the question